# Javascript height calculating and positioning

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm working on a website where I list 12 post in a 3x4 grid. I'm using absolute positioning with a JS code that calculate the top and left position of each box (I'm using this method, because every post has different height and it has to be in left-to-right order. If there's any better solution I'm open for it.)

I'm using .outerHeight() to get each post's height and calculate the top position. In the end I choose the biggest column height and set it as the container height.

My problem is: when I open the page the JS code make the layout I want and it usually works. But there is some try, when it gets the bad value and every column vertically slip together and it also calculate the bad height for the container.

How can I make this work everytime? Thank you for the help!

My code:

```
function latestPostLayout() {
      var count = 0;

      $(".latest-post:first-child").css({
        top: "0",
        left: "0",
      });

      var width = $(".latest-post:first-child").outerWidth();
      $(".latest-post:nth-child(2)").css({
        top: 0,
        left: width,
      });

      var width2 = width + $(".latest-post:nth-child(2)").outerWidth();

      $(".latest-post:nth-child(3)").css({
        top: 0,
        left: width2,
      });

      var count = 0;
      var height0 = $(".latest-post:nth-child(1)").outerHeight();

      var height1 = $(".latest-post:nth-child(2)").outerHeight();
      var height2 = $(".latest-post:nth-child(3)").outerHeight();
      $(".latest-post:gt(2)").each(function () {
        if (count == 0) {
          $(this).css({
            top: height0,
            left: 0,
          });

          height0 += $(this).outerHeight();
        } else if (count == 1) {
          $(this).css({
            top: height1,
            left: width,
          });

          height1 += $(this).outerHeight();
        } else if (count == 2) {
          $(this).css({
            top: height2,
            left: width2,
          });

          height2 += $(this).outerHeight();
        }

        count += 1;
        if (count > 2) {
          count = 0;
        }
      });

      $(".dnh-latest-posts").css({
        height: Math.max(height0, height1, height2),
      });
    }
```

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS Grid. It was made to solve complex grid requirements like this.

The CSS would be something like this:

```css
    .container {
      display: grid;
      /* To make equal width columns */
      /* assuming you want 3 cols per row */
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      /* To make equal height rows */
      /* assuming you have 4 rows (because 12/3 = 4) */
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
```

Grid columns' height in a row will use/match the height of the biggest column in that row, kind of like if you were using the HTML table element.